# UIImageView with iOS 7 not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, ios7

I have an app I was building for iOS 6 that I recently upgraded to iOS 7. I have a `UIScrollView` with a few Custom `UIViews`. Within those `UIViews`, I have a single `UIImageView` in each. For some reason, when I set the `UIImageView.image` in iOS 6, it shows up fine, but iOS 7 will not show them. Here's the code:

```
int i = 0;

        for (UIImageView *imageView in myImageViewsOutletCollection)
        {
            imageView.image = nil;
            if (imagesArray.count > i)
                imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i]];

            if (imageView.image == nil)
                NSLog(@"signature image with index: %i is nil", i);
                    else
                            NSLog(@"It Worked")

            i++;
        }
```

My app is logging: `@"It Worked"`, so I know the `UIImageView.image` isn't `nil`. What could I be doing wrong?

EDIT:

I tried the UIImageRenderingMode:

```
UIImage *imageForView = [UIImage imageWithData:[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
imageForView = [imageForView imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

imageView.image = imageForView;
```

Still didn't work. However, @Max_Power89 said:

> as it is written on the apple developer forum : imageWithData bug
>   report
>
> this must be a bug. i hope they fix the problem early.

EDIT 2:

I also added this:

```
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docs = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSError *writeError = nil;
[pngData writeToFile:[docs stringByAppendingFormat:@"/image.png"] options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writeError];
if(writeError!=nil)
{
    NSLog(@"%@: Error saving image: %@", [self class], [writeError localizedDescription]);
}
```

The image was saved in app's directory, so I know for certain that the image isn't nil.

Comment: log the size of the image views

Comment: @Wain - NSLog of frame was `0,0,320,120` No problems there

Comment: Do we have a working solution for this? I am experiencing the same issue. This also goes for `UITableView` :(

Comment: It seems to be a bug with the Auto-Layout constraints. As soon as I adjusted the constraints it seemed to work fine. Play around with constraints

Comment: I have same problem, did you fix it?  I find if I press Home button and go back in all the views appear, iOS6 is fine.  I am sure this is AutoLayout thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem/bug with Auto Layout constraints in iOS 7. If you remove the constraints on the `UIView`, it works no problem. You can set frames programmatically if you need to.

Comment: but some images can show with contraints. really weird.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 7, loading a image by default only load it's alpha Chanel, and tint it with detail tint color. Your image is showing, just that it's the same color with the background.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithRenderingMode:(UIImageRenderingMode)renderingMode
```

Set it to:

```
UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal
```

Comment: So, how do I fix that? - @Kyle Fang

Comment: Sorry, I just made a guess. you should contact the guy in the link... He said that it's a project specific problem. Maybe he could help

Answer (score 0):

as it is written on the apple developer forum : [imageWithData bug report](https://devforums.apple.com/message/857998#857998)

this must be a bug. i hope they fix the problem early.

Comment: Hmm, that could be it. However, code doesn't seem to be returning nil.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be helpful to anyone: I was having the same issue - al least it looked like this. In the end I figured out, that an **UIScrollView** was hiding some background view layers. The UIScrollView-background was set to "**Group Table View Background Color**" in the .xib-File. If I changed that to "clear color" the behavior went back to normal (like in iOS 6). Seems, that the "default behavior" changed for that element from iOS6 to 7. Maybe someone is able to confirm this.